# Not able to run shell script in busybox without mounting procfs

Tags: linux, shell, sh, busybox

I am trying to run a shell script in busybox rootfs with linux kernel version 4.4.4. Test script tries to mount procfs.

```
#!/bin/sh  
mount -t proc none /proc
```

I can run this script with `sh test.sh`, but if I tries to run using `./test.sh`, it says `/bin/sh test.sh not found`. Strange thing is after mounting procfs manually

```
mount -t proc none /proc
```

I can run `./test.sh`. For busybox I am using default config with static enabled.

Comment: Should that be "test.sh" or "tesh.sh"?

Comment: What is the output of `type sh` before you run any of this?

Comment: it is test.sh. Below is output of     / # type sh
    sh is /bin/sh

Comment: can you able to locate the path of sh manually?

Comment: yes, it is inside /bin

Comment: Check if you have set executable permission for your script. If not then use ```chmod +x test.sh``` to set executable permission and then use ```./test.sh``` command to run your script

Comment: I have set the executable permission, strange thing is it just work after mounting the procfs.